# Split text based on Column Difference Into Multiple Files

Tags: sorting, awk, sed, cut

I have this data concerning trajectory information, below:

```
EP, 13, 2017071012, 03, AP01, 126, 27.1, -130, 17, 1018, XX, 34, NEQ, 0000, 0000, 0000, 0000
AL, 07, 2017071012, 03, AP01, 132, 27, -131.1, 18, 1018, XX, 34, NEQ, 0000, 0000, 0000, 0000
WP, 19, 2017071012, 03, AP01, 000, 18.5, -116.8, 56, 982, XX, 50, NEQ, 0057, 0047, 0034, 0036
AL, 08, 2017071012, 03, AP01, 132, 27, -132.1, 17, 1018, XX, 34, NEQ, 0000, 0000, 0000, 0000
```

The information needs to be sorted by the 1st (name) and 2nd (numerical identifier) columns.

Running

```
sort -k1,2 file.txt
```

organizes the file into:

```
AL, 07, 2017071012, 03, AP01, 132, 27, -131.1, 18, 1018, XX, 34, NEQ, 0000, 0000, 0000, 0000
AL, 08, 2017071012, 03, AP01, 132, 27, -132.1, 17, 1018, XX, 34, NEQ, 0000, 0000, 0000, 0000
EP, 13, 2017071012, 03, AP01, 126, 27.1, -130, 17, 1018, XX, 34, NEQ, 0000, 0000, 0000, 0000
WP, 19, 2017071012, 03, AP01, 000, 18.5, -116.8, 56, 982, XX, 50, NEQ, 0057, 0047, 0034, 0036
```

This is a step to what is desired.

I need to separate the data into separate files based on the second column - how would that be done? I imagine some type of regular expression is needed. Additionally, the second column is always numerical, and will not contain negative integers.

(The first column will always start with AL, EP, or WP)

Thank you for your information and help in advance!

Comment: What do you mean? For the given sample, do you want to create files `07`, `08`, `13`, and `19` with the respective lines?

Comment: @choroba - yes, or arbitrary filenames with regards to those lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort -k1,2 file.txt | awk -F', *' '{print > ("out" $2)}'
```

If you are not using GNU awk and you file has a lot of unique "$2" values then you'll need to close the files as you go, e.g. at its simplest:

```
sort -k1,2 file.txt | awk -F', *' '{f="out" $2; print >> f; close(f)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -aF'/,\s/' -ne 'open my $OUT, ">>", $F[1] or die $!;
                     print {$OUT} $_;' -- sorted-file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-aF` splits each line on the given pattern `/,\s/`, i.e. comma + space, and populates the @F array with the results
- `>>` means the file is opened for appending